# Is it possible to make a TypeScript function return never (or throw) if a generic type extends a subtype without casting?

Tags: typescript

(There is no genuine use-case here, so this *is* my code)

I'm trying to make a function that throws an error if the string is "fish". I was successfully able to do this by using `as`, however,
is there any way to avoid using `as` for this scenario?

```
function throwIfFish<S extends string>(string: S): S extends "fish" ? never : S {
    if (string === "fish") {
        throw new Error("fish");
    }
    return string as S extends "fish" ? never : S;
    //            ^ is this unavoidable?
}
```

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFAFgJzgdwJLAGIwDOKAPAMqICmAHlJWACaGKFRoxgDmAfABSvsuALkRkAlCIo06jZgCJgRFHMQB%20RGEoA3SmkSTEAbwBQiM4hjBE-Nh06IAvE8QKlcsUdPnvqDJg2U-gCiaBhovK7E7gDcXmYAvnGIAPTJiAASWIgQAIZI2Ig5WnAwDIgghHYuOYQqHMgoRCwwUCA5sAiqSWiUrWhIAlU1olS09EwuilFqATp6krGJxqmIKHBziOu6DZSIoJAdSLkANsfIcCyUuy3MUACeAA6UxhAIrIjUjg1%20uATEEVNlGIXm8oIg7l9fFhfkoInRWO4gA)

Comment: This is a basic limitation of TS; the type checker cannot verify that a value is assignable to a conditional type that depends on generic type parameter.  See https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/33912

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The conditional type in question is simple enough, and the result type is "good enough" so that index signature type can work here:

```js
type NeverFish<S extends string> = {
    fish: never;
    [n: string]: S;
}

function throwIfFish<S extends string>(str: S): NeverFish<S>[S] {
    if (str === "fish") {
        throw new Error("fish");
    } else { 
        return str; 
    }
}


let r1 = throwIfFish("f");    // "f"
let r2 = throwIfFish("fish"); // never
```

Answer (score 1):

Move the signature into another overload:

```
function throwIfFish<S extends string>(string: S): S extends "fish" ? never : S;
function throwIfFish(string: string) {
    if (string === "fish") {
        throw new Error("fish");
    }

    return string;
}
```

but this means TypeScript will no longer check if the implementation coheres to the overload's signature. Alternatively, you could still use a cast with less repetition:

```
return string as ReturnType<typeof throwIfFish<S>>;
```

Comment: Oh, I do hope you'll go on to explain that this is "morally equivalent" to a type assertion, since function overloads are intentionally checked loosely.  You're not getting type safety verification here